# 2 different sites in one place

Tags: php

Im trying to have 2 different sites in one place, first site with wordpress and second one without wordpress, when visitors come from affiliate.webmediamagazine.com to be loaded wordpress, and direct to be loaded another custom index, I'm using the codes below:

http://affiliate.webmediamagazine.com/index.php

```
<form action='http://www.webmediamagazine.com' method='post' name='frm'>
<input type='hidden' name="affiliate" value="yes">
</form>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.frm.submit();
</script>
```

http://webmediamagazine.com/index.php

```
<?php 
$affiliate = $_POST['affiliate'];
if ($affiliate == yes) {include 'indexwp.php';} 
else {include 'indexcustom.php';}
?>
```

indexwp.php is wordpress default index.php
indexcustom.php is a simple php script.

Comment: And ... what is your question?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you don't do this via the web server and you want to do this in code?

Comment: I think this might be better handled with e.g. a htaccess file, checking referrer.

Comment: Ok, what **exactly** are you trying to do? Do you need to open different pages for `affiliate.webmediamagazine.com` and `webmediamagazine.com` or you need to know, if the **visitor** visited one of those pages *before* he came to your `mysite.com` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be configured as Virtual Hosts in your server (Apache? Nginx? ...?) config files.

[Example for Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

**EDIT:**

On a shared hosting, you could put your wordpress files in the `~/www/wordpress/` folder for example.

Then you make the subdomain (`affiliate.webmediamagazine.com`) point to this directory. Most of the time it can be done in the admin panel provided by your host.

Comment: Or maybe you're on a shared hosting service and cannot access to the server configuration...

Comment: @AlbiHoti Even when you're on shared hosting, if the provider uses Apache then you can still use a [`.htaccess`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file.

Comment: but will be the link same for both
affiliate.webmediamgazine.com -> webmediamagazine.com (wordpress site)
webmediamagazine.com -> php file
?

Answer (score 1):

If you really mean like this ***...when visitors come from...***, then just use simple redirect:

```
<?

switch ( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ) {
    default:
      header( 'Location: /indexcustom.php' ); die;
    break;
    case 'affiliate.webmediamagazine.com':
      header( 'Location: /indexwp.php' ); die;
    break;
}

?>
```

Or use **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**, if you need to know, what `domain` the visitor is in.

But as others already said, in this case it is better to configure it all in `apache` level to use different directory with a clean WordPress installation.

*EDIT*

Are you sure you didn't forget the `'` around the word *yes* in your code?

```
<?php 
    $affiliate = $_POST['affiliate'];
    if ($affiliate == 'yes') { include 'indexwp.php'; } 
    else {include 'indexcustom.php';}
?>
```

Comment: updated with this but nothing happens, its not loading indexwp.php even if referer is affiliate.webmediamagazine.com

Comment: What does `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` prints?

Comment: not prints nothing, maybe that is in POST form and not a redirect

Answer (score 0):

I did it now, using php cookie to store but not from subdomain but only from directory.